# Stuck in MySQL command prompt

Tags: mysql

I was into the MySQL command prompt and want to get out of it. No queries are working for me. Please see the screenshot:

[image: MySQL prompt]

I am running it on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.7.

Comment: mysql running on localhost?

Comment: please have a look here http://superuser.com/questions/629709/how-to-exit-mysql-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to forcefully get out of the process. The problem lies with big schemas where the processing takes a longer period of time.